# Error while signing into Azure Data warehouse using SSMS from Internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, ssms, azure-synapse, multi-factor-authentication

We have MFA enabled for users in Azure AD, currently when I am trying to access the Azure Data Warehouse using authentication method as `Azure Active Directory - Universal with MFA` and click on Connect I am getting error on the Pop-up saying "`object doesn't support this property or method "includes`" (screenshot below)

I verified the setting in IE and check whether Java script is enabled or not and also verified it with other servers settings in IE where its working but still not able to fix this error on one of our azure server.

Once I click on connect it should pop-up a window asking for password and after clicking on sign-in it asks for verification and then sign-in us to access data warehouse from SSMS but in my case the error doesn't allow the pop-up screen to appear.

Could anyone please guide me with the steps to resolve this error?

[image]

Comment: Internet Explorer ran out of support a long time ago; it's long past time you updated your preferred browser.

Comment: @Thom A, yes, I am aware and I also have Edge and Google chrome installed on the server and I have set default browser as Edge in default windows setting but not sure why it still pops-up this error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I had reported has been resolved.

After clearing the browsing history/cache of the IE browser the error was gone and the pop-up windows asking for password appeared.

Thank you.